# Is it safe to run the upgrade process even though it says many packages will be removed?

Tags: upgrade

I’ve been using a Dell 5520-Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, laptop for some time, and wondering if anyone that uses this same laptop and OS has successfully upraded to 18.04 LTS. I went through the download and upgrade process yesterday, but canceled it at the last minute after it notified me that 62 programs would be disabled.

Comment: Is it possible for you to copy the list of 62 programs and post that here? It maybe that many of them are from `ppas` which are disabled by the upgrade process. Before that, you could edit your question to include the output of `grep -Ev '(^#|^ *$|deb-src)' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

Comment: The message occured in the terminal durring the upgrade download process. I can't remember the term that was used, It might have stated 62 packages, (probably not programs.) But no. It didn't give me a list. It stated 62 "something" were to be disabled, and another rather large number to be upgraded. Thats when I decided against it.

Comment: The larger number to be upgraded is to be expected. Can you add the output of the code I requested to your question?

Comment: I can not post the output. The forum will not let me post the links, and or the comment is too long

Comment: Okay, do you know how to use pastebin? If so, you can upload to pastebin and post that link here. For that, you may need to install `pastebinit`.

Comment: I added an image of output at start of post

Comment: I don't think you need to focus too much on what you're losing.  Upgrading from one version to another usually leads to programs being removed because they are not supported.  Instead of the number of programs (62), you should look at whether the 62 is something that you *need* to do your work/studies.  Keep in mind if that is the case, you might be able to get it in Ubuntu 18.04 with a PPA or it might never be in any future Ubuntu and you'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: My intent was to learn of any potential device or driver issues. This laptop was built with Ubuntu in mind, albeit 16.04LTS, so that's one plus, but I would never expect an OS upgrade to go without a hitch. That's seem niave. I was just hoping that someone with this same puter may have already tried the new version, and could give me an idea of what to expect. At-any-rate, thx for your comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ubuntu upgrade there are pretty much ALWAYS discarded programs and libraries, usually replaced with some new tools. this is what installer is telling you about.
Please be aware no configs are removed for those programs, so if you miss the program you should be able to install it manually and reuse the configs you have in your /home dir.
I would still advise a backup and full fresh install :) Dell laptops work very well with default ubuntu installation (multiple dells user here)

Comment: That's good to hear. I just made an image of my drive just in case. I'll try the  upgrade tommorrow. THX.

Comment: @  DK Bose: I took a few images of the Ubuntu upgrade. If you still want to see the packages/programs that Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS wanted to  remove You can see them in link below. I named the pertinent images *obsolete*. There was actually quite a few that new version wanted gone. Surprisingly the install was smoothest Linux install ever for me. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rf8J95vRQncU_DgxE2NSQz7HC9kmdPqX?usp=sharing

Comment: looks good. the only thing i would reinstall later seems to be nvidia drivers, but others seems to be old libs and deprecated packages

Comment: I appreciate your assessment though my inept understanding of Linux command-set. Running "ubuntu-drivers-devices" in terminal resulted in this.    == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013B6sv00001028sd000007BFbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107GLM [Quadro M1200 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : config-prime-select-intel-all - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin                    What would you suggest?

Comment: I ran "sudo apt install nvidia-390" and result was, Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-390 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libnvidia-gl-390 nvidia-kernel-source-390:i386
  nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390:i386 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
  nvidia-kernel-source-390 nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390

Comment: `nvidia-driver-390` should still be available in the official repo

Comment: Yes. I eventually found it on Nvidia site, and installed it. I was later reading about a bug that had to do with a the driver causing big power drain. I guess runs it constantly. I turned it off and went back to the intel driver. Weird thing; at first the 390 driver was recommended, but after I removed it the 410 driver was recommended. I installed it and now the Nvidia settings will not open.